# Find out what links to a specific node - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Does anyone know of a good module (or technique) that can be used to find out what other nodes may link to a specific node.

For example, I have a node with id 1000, and I'm going to be renaming the path for it.  I want to know what other nodes link to it (links made in the body of the node) so I can quickly go back and update those nodes as well.

Any thoughts?  This site isn't accessible to normal link checkers, so it would have to be something on the site itself, or a FF extension, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the [Link Checker](http://drupal.org/project/linkchecker) module. It finds broken links and redirects, so it won't find all references to a node until after you move it. But it will give you a full report of broken and redirected links on your site, and even gives options for automatically updating or unpublishing the affected nodes. You should be able to install the module, do the move, scan for broken links using Link Checker, then fix the links.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for note!  I have heard of this module, but I wasn't 100% sure if it was a site wide search, or what.  So... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you say you're going to be changing the path of the node I'm assuming that you mean that you're going to be changing the node ID, right?

The module that Greg mentions sounds good in this case.

If all you're doing is creating a new alias for the node then the old links should still work as the node ID hasn't changed.

Comment: The node id will remain the same, but the alias to that node.  The problem is that I linked to the node on other pages, and the alias is not the same anymore (the links were to the alias).  So, the link won't work.